# Advantage of intermediate representations after compilation

Tags: java, jvm, javac, intermediate-language

Whats the point of having an intermediate representation after compilation (for eg Java has bytecode) if you still have to design a separate software (JVM in this case) for every platform ? 
I mean platform dependency is still there!!

Comment: Write Once, Run Anywhere is the slogan. It should be Compile Once, Run Anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Whats the point of having an intermediate representation after
>   compilation (for eg Java has bytecode) if you still have to design a
>   separate software (JVM in this case) for every platform ?

Because you don't have to re-write and re-compile it on all/different platforms. This is the beauty of java Write once run anywhere feature.

Being a developer I need not to worry which OS platform my code will run. I simply need to compile and provide the classes, which will be valid for all the platforms for the same java version.

Comment: thats the shortest most effective explanation!

Comment: I was thinking since interpretation is slower, why isnt the bytecode converted to machine code via compilation?

Answer (score 2):

So that *you* don't need to write the code for every platform.

Answer (score 0):

Write once - Use anywhere

that's a principal of java Bytecode